# Transformation of local volatility model

Tags: volatility, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, local-volatility, differential-equations

Assume we have an SDE
$$dX_t=\mu(X_t)dt + \sigma(X_t)dW_t$$
where $\sigma>0$ and $W_t$ is a Wiener process. Is there a transformation $y(X_t)$ that will make the dynamics of the transformed process $Y_t=y(X_t)$ have constant volatility?

Comment: The (almost trivial) case is of course $\mu(X)=\mu\times X$ and $\sigma(X)=\sigma\times X$. Then,$y=\ln(X)$ yields constant vol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is called the Lamperti transform. [This](http://henrikmadsen.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Report_-_2010_-_From_State_Dependent_Diffusion_to_Constant_Diffusion_in_Stochastic_Differential_Equations_by_the_Lamperti_Transform.pdf) document, in particular Theorem 2, page 7, describes what the Lamperti transform is.

Comment: Nice, I did not know that this topic has been studied -  thanks!

Comment: Thanks, had not heard this term before.

Answer (score 5):

Consider a function $f(X_t)$. Ito's lemma gives:

$$df(X_t)=\text{time terms}+f'(X_t)\sigma(X_t)dW_t$$

Now any $f$ satisfying:

$$f'(X_t)\sigma(X_t)=\text{constant}$$

gives a constant volatility for $f(X_t)$. Solving $f$ requires specifying  $\sigma(X_t)$. For example, and as pointed out by Kermittfrog in the comments,  when $\sigma(X_t)=\sigma X_t$, you can set $f(X_t)=\log(X_t)$.